# Aligning text in list with the span beside it

Tags: html, css, web

Good day, beginner here just want to ask i'm trying to create a list just like the one in the image attached, should use an `li` tag and add a span beside it?

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Accessories</a>
    <span>6%</span>
</li>
```

but what happens when `li` tag have longer text the numbers beside it do not align vertically when I add margin to the span to separate them.

**Sample:**

[image: sample image]

**Result:**

[image: result image]

Comment: can you please post the result of your error in list. What goes wrong?

Comment: sorry for the unclear question, the one im trying to replicate is the one in the sample image attached but what happens is the the one in the result image when i tried to put margin-left in the span to seperate them.

Comment: answered check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make you `li` flex and use justify content space between:

```css
.flex {
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex>li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.flex span {
  margin-left: 1em;
  /*bit of spacing between link and span in case text is very long */
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Accessories</a>
    <span>6%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Another</a>
    <span>16%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">And Another that might have long text that could spill over 2 lines</a>
    <span>12%</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The advantages of using flex over float:

- you don't need a clear fix
- if your anchor is over multiple lines, your span stays on the same line rather than being pushed underneath
- floats were never intended to be used to layout documents like that so don't abuse them, now css has progressed, use proper techniques instead

Answer (score 0):

Create an order list and set list type none then set span to float right,With that the span always be floated to right. This method is quite simple and responsive the other methods like margin and spacing are good as well but they aren't responsive and easily break in small devices

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:20px;
  width:200px;
}
span{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Computer<span>$6</span></p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Computer<span>$6</span></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add style to

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Accessories</a>
   <span style="float: right;">6%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Accessorieaaaaa</a>
   <span style="float: right;">6%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Access</a>
   <span style="float: right;">6%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">As</a>
   <span style="float: right";>6%</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I SUGGEST you to use the span tag between the list tags and use the margin attribute to fix the space between them.

Comment: suggestions are welcomed in comment section rather than whole new answer. So avoid it

Comment: Didn't you do the same thing i wrote just in another example ?

Comment: you suggest and I answered